# best practice to handle UI size constant in universal app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm about to convert my iPhone app into an iPad app.
The iPad app UI mostly like a double size iPhone app.
Many parts of my iPhone UI is done by code, so I have quite many constants that need to be multiplied to double in iPad version:

```
CGFloat scale = (IS_IPAD) ? 2 : 1;
kCellHeight = 140 * scale;
```

It's just like a pain to write code for all of these constants.

What is a good approach to handle this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use [`[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale) instead which is designed to check the difference between Retina & Non-Retina displays.
- Use [`[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/userInterfaceIdiom), or better, the [`UI_USER_ITERFACE_IDIOM`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM) macro, to check if you are on iPad or iPhone.
- If you need your app to be generated both for iPhone and iPad and have multiple constants that have to be doubled for the iPad version/target, define a macro for this, like explained below

---

*[EDIT] : Tip to use a macro for this*

**If you want to create a single app** that will run on iPhone or iPad, and need the values to be determined at Runtime, use sthg like this:

```
#define ZoomOnIPad(x) (UI_USER_ITERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? (x) : (2*x)
```

**If you want to create two differents apps**, one for iPad and one version for iPhone (for example defining two different targets in your Xcode project), and thus that your values can be determined at compile time, define a preprocessor macro with a different value for your two targets so that you can differenciate them (e.g. define IPAD_TARGET in your iPad target and don't define it in your iPhone target), then use sthg like this:

```
#ifdef IPAD_TARGET
  #define ZoomOnIPad(x) 2*x
#else
  #define ZoomOnIPad(x) x
#endif
```

Then of course use it this way:

```
kCellHeight = ZoomOnIPad(140);
```

Comment: I end up doing a modified solution, so that I have more control when I don't want to double: `#define iui(x, y) ((IS_IPAD)? (y): (x))`, `#define kCellHeight iui(140, 280)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the iPad screen and the iPhone screen don't have the same proportions(iPad's width/height ratio is 0.75 and iPhone's is 0.66) . The difference is small indeed, but if you literally take an iPhone app and make it double in size you will not be able to fill the entire iPad screen.

So, you need to make your layout flexible to those changes either by using autoresizing masks or manually (eg.  button x value is 0.34*screenSize.width) if you didn't use UIKit for the interface. This is easier than keeping 2 sets of coordinates.